# Write output function to sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this function to load a XML feed into Google Sheet:

By typing `=loadOutposts()` in a field it writes the data into that sheet.

```
function loadOutposts(){
  var outposts= new Array();
  var url = "https://api.eveonline.com/eve/ConquerableStationList.xml.aspx";
  var parameters = {method : "get", payload : ""};
  var xmlFeed = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters).getContentText();
  var xml = XmlService.parse(xmlFeed);
  if(xml) {
    var rows=xml.getRootElement().getChild("result").getChild("rowset").getChildren("row");
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      outpost=[rows[i].getAttribute("stationID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("stationName").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("stationTypeID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("solarSystemID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("corporationID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("corporationName").getValue()
                 ]
      outposts.push(outpost);
    }
  }
  return outposts;
}
```

I want to control in the function where to write the data but i don't know how.

Current situation: I need to type '=loadOutposts()' in a field to run this function and show the data in that field.

Preferred situation: I would like to set the field where the output shows in the function and run the function from the script editor.

Comment: Your code here has a couple of ways it could be improved. First, you might want to actually declare `outpost` with `var`. Also, please take a look at this fiddle for how I made your code a bit more concise. It's unclear what you want, so if it doesn't work as you expect, please excuse me: https://jsfiddle.net/g4gudqa1/. Finally, if google sheets accepts CSV files as an import, why not just put the data in that format?

Comment: Consider using the built-in function `=importXML`

Comment: @Pytth Thank you for your improvements. 

Current situation: I need to type '=loadOutposts()' in a field to run this function and show the data in that field.

Preferred situation: I would like to set the field where the output shows in the function and run the function from the script editor.

Comment: Use [Range()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), before setting the value. This will allows users to access and modify ranges in Google Sheets. A range can be a single cell in a sheet or a range of cells in a sheet. You can check this tutorial on how to [Update Multiple Cell Values in Google Sheets with Apps Script](https://ctrlq.org/code/20504-update-google-sheet-cell-values). Hope this helps.